# Foreach saving only the first item data

Tags: magento-1.9, php, model, performance

I have an array with a list of products, and I wanna save each of its attributes in a table. Its a list of 25 products, but it saves the first product's attributes 25 times.
Here is my code:

```
$promo = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/promotion');
foreach ($return['response']['diffgrdiffgram']['NewDataSet']['Produtos'] as $product) {
    $promo->setName($product['DESCRICAO']);
    $promo->setIdProduct($product['CODIGO']);
    $promo->setPromoPrice($product['PRECOREVENDA']);
    $promo->setDescrtec($product['DESCRTEC']);
    $promo->setCategory($product['CATEGORIA']);
    $promo->setManufacturer($product['FABRICANTE']);
    $promo->setDepartment($product['DEPARTAMENTO']);
    $promo->setPartnumber($product['PARTNUMBER']);
    $promo->setEan($product['EAN']);
    $promo->setWarranty($product['GARANTIA']);
    $promo->setWeight($product['PESOKG']);
    $promo->setResalePrice($product['PRECOREVENDA']);
    $promo->setPriceWithoutSt($product['PRECOSEMST']);
    $promo->setExpireDate($product['DATAVALIDADEPRECO']);
    $promo->setAvailable($product['DISPONIVEL']);
    $promo->setPic($product['URLFOTOPRODUTO']);
    $promo->setStock($product['ESTOQUE']);
    $promo->setNcm($product['NCM']);
    $promo->setWidth($product['LARGURA']);
    $promo->setHeight($product['ALTURA']);
    $promo->setDepth($product['PROFUNDIDADE']);
    $promo->setActive($product['ATIVO']);
    $promo->setSubstTributaria($product['SUBSTTRIBUTARIA']);
    $promo->setProductOrigin($product['ORIGEMPRODUTO']);
    $promo->setAvailableStock($product['ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL']);
    $promo->setUpdatedAt($product['TIMESTAMP']);
    $promo->save();
}
```

Is there something wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put Object in foreach it's take a time and everytime new object create. use just set `$promo->setId(null)` it's working. check it.

```
$promo = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/promotion');
    foreach ($return['response']['diffgrdiffgram']['NewDataSet']['Produtos'] as $product) {
        $promo->setName($product['DESCRICAO']);
        $promo->setIdProduct($product['CODIGO']);
        $promo->setPromoPrice($product['PRECOREVENDA']);
        $promo->setDescrtec($product['DESCRTEC']);
        $promo->setCategory($product['CATEGORIA']);
        $promo->setManufacturer($product['FABRICANTE']);
        $promo->setDepartment($product['DEPARTAMENTO']);
        $promo->setPartnumber($product['PARTNUMBER']);
        $promo->setEan($product['EAN']);
        $promo->setWarranty($product['GARANTIA']);
        $promo->setWeight($product['PESOKG']);
        $promo->setResalePrice($product['PRECOREVENDA']);
        $promo->setPriceWithoutSt($product['PRECOSEMST']);
        $promo->setExpireDate($product['DATAVALIDADEPRECO']);
        $promo->setAvailable($product['DISPONIVEL']);
        $promo->setPic($product['URLFOTOPRODUTO']);
        $promo->setStock($product['ESTOQUE']);
        $promo->setNcm($product['NCM']);
        $promo->setWidth($product['LARGURA']);
        $promo->setHeight($product['ALTURA']);
        $promo->setDepth($product['PROFUNDIDADE']);
        $promo->setActive($product['ATIVO']);
        $promo->setSubstTributaria($product['SUBSTTRIBUTARIA']);
        $promo->setProductOrigin($product['ORIGEMPRODUTO']);
        $promo->setAvailableStock($product['ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL']);
        $promo->setUpdatedAt($product['TIMESTAMP']);
        $promo->setId(null);
        $promo->save();
    }
```

Comment: It worked! Really faster, too. Thank you very much. Can you explain what setId(null) is for, please?

Comment: Your Wel come. Programming logic.

Comment: it's means when object insert new records it's id set null so don't need to create again.  if you only set it to "NULL" Magento will only think you don't want to update the value.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have created `$promo` object outside for-each loop.

```
foreach ($return['response']['diffgrdiffgram']['NewDataSet']['Produtos'] as $product) {
    $promo = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/promotion');
    $promo->setName($product['DESCRICAO']);
    $promo->setIdProduct($product['CODIGO']);
    $promo->setPromoPrice($product['PRECOREVENDA']);
    $promo->setDescrtec($product['DESCRTEC']);
    $promo->setCategory($product['CATEGORIA']);
    $promo->setManufacturer($product['FABRICANTE']);
    $promo->setDepartment($product['DEPARTAMENTO']);
    $promo->setPartnumber($product['PARTNUMBER']);
    $promo->setEan($product['EAN']);
    $promo->setWarranty($product['GARANTIA']);
    $promo->setWeight($product['PESOKG']);
    $promo->setResalePrice($product['PRECOREVENDA']);
    $promo->setPriceWithoutSt($product['PRECOSEMST']);
    $promo->setExpireDate($product['DATAVALIDADEPRECO']);
    $promo->setAvailable($product['DISPONIVEL']);
    $promo->setPic($product['URLFOTOPRODUTO']);
    $promo->setStock($product['ESTOQUE']);
    $promo->setNcm($product['NCM']);
    $promo->setWidth($product['LARGURA']);
    $promo->setHeight($product['ALTURA']);
    $promo->setDepth($product['PROFUNDIDADE']);
    $promo->setActive($product['ATIVO']);
    $promo->setSubstTributaria($product['SUBSTTRIBUTARIA']);
    $promo->setProductOrigin($product['ORIGEMPRODUTO']);
    $promo->setAvailableStock($product['ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL']);
    $promo->setUpdatedAt($product['TIMESTAMP']);
    $promo->save();
}
```

Please try above code. It will create new object each time and save data.

Thanks :)

Comment: It worked! Just one question: I've been told before to never load models in a loop because it kills performance, that would be just for the method load? E.g:    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());    Is it okay to instantiate a model in a loop?

Comment: if you want to load product then you can declare model outside loop and then load each product inside loop. For example,  `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
foreach ($product_id_array as $product_id){
    $product = $product->load($product_id);
    echo $product->getName() . " - " . $product->getFinalPrice . "<br/>";
}`

Comment: Never you instantiate a model in a loop, with this solution you will load 25 times a model, you find this fine ??

Comment: I see! I missinterpreted it then. I thought "you can't load a model inside a loop" meant "you can't instantiate a model inside a loop". My bad! Thanks for your help

Comment: Prince, do you mind helping me with some other way, then? This worked fine, but if there is a better and faster way, I'd like to see it, for performance is one of my priorities

Comment: Please look my answer

Answer (score 0):

As I have said before, **Never** you you instantiate a model in loop !

I dont tested it but try this one :

```
$promo = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/promotion');
foreach ($return['response']['diffgrdiffgram']['NewDataSet']['Produtos'] as $product) {
    $promo->setName($product['DESCRICAO'])
          ->setIdProduct($product['CODIGO'])
          ->setPromoPrice($product['PRECOREVENDA'])
          ->setDescrtec($product['DESCRTEC'])
          ->setCategory($product['CATEGORIA'])
          ->setManufacturer($product['FABRICANTE'])
          ->setDepartment($product['DEPARTAMENTO'])
          ->setPartnumber($product['PARTNUMBER'])
          ->setEan($product['EAN'])
          ->setWarranty($product['GARANTIA'])
          ->setWeight($product['PESOKG'])
          ->setResalePrice($product['PRECOREVENDA'])
          ->setPriceWithoutSt($product['PRECOSEMST'])
          ->setExpireDate($product['DATAVALIDADEPRECO'])
          ->setAvailable($product['DISPONIVEL'])
          ->setPic($product['URLFOTOPRODUTO'])
          ->setStock($product['ESTOQUE'])
          ->setNcm($product['NCM'])
          ->setWidth($product['LARGURA'])
          ->setHeight($product['ALTURA'])
          ->setDepth($product['PROFUNDIDADE'])
          ->setActive($product['ATIVO'])
          ->setSubstTributaria($product['SUBSTTRIBUTARIA'])
          ->setProductOrigin($product['ORIGEMPRODUTO'])
          ->setAvailableStock($product['ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL'])
          ->setUpdatedAt($product['TIMESTAMP']);
    $promo->save();
    $promo->unsetData();
}
```